# Why using "re.I" flag in findall() function gives different results when function is used on the compiled regex object vs function used by itself

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm studying Python by myself and was not able to find explanation for this behavior:

When the regex object is first compiled and **findall()** method is used on the compiled regex object with **re.I** flag, the result is different than by using **findall()** function with the same flag by itself.

(Removing **re.I** flag from *result* variable "fixes" the dissimilarity of results.)

```
import re

emails1 = re.compile(r"([A-z0-9._+-]+@[A-z0-9._+-]+\.[A-z]{2,})")
result = emails1.findall("xxx@yyy.com", re.I)
print(result)
>>>['x@yyy.com']

emails2 = re.findall(r"([A-z0-9._+-]+@[A-z0-9._+-]+\.[A-z]{2,})", "xxx@yyy.com", re.I)
print(emails2)
>>>['xxx@yyy.com']
```

Appreciate any help or advice!

Comment: To avoid the signature confusion, you might consider embedding that flag as `r"(?i:[\w\d._+-]+@[\w\d._+-]+\.\w{2,})"`.  You realize that `[A-z]` also drags in `[\]_^`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `findall` method on a compiled regex has a different parameter signature than the `findall` function.

Function

```
findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

Method

```
findall(string, pos=0, endpos=9223372036854775807)
```

`re.I` is an enumeration with a value of 2, so you are really asking the compiled method to start at position 2, ignoring that first "xx".

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you're telling `findall()` to start at position 2 of the string. (`re.I` has the integer value 2.)  So it skips the first two characters of the string.

If you look at the method signature of the `findall()` method you'll find that the second argument is `pos`, not `flags`. That's because you have to pass the flags at the time the regular expression is compiled, because they are baked in to the compiled regex object.  You can't specify them later.